# Unable to set GroupId in spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams:3.1.1

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams:3.1.1` with functional programming. I have tried a number of combinations to set GroupId but the Consumer is always printing GroupId as the spring.application.name.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nt.utility</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-messages</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kafka-messages</name>
    <description>Kafka Messages</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lombok-version>1.16.8</lombok-version>
        <maven-version>2.2.4.RELEASE</maven-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <shutdown>kill</shutdown>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Java code**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaMessageApplication {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaMessageApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> process() {
        return input -> input;
    }
}
```

***application.yml***

```
spring:
  application.name: kafka-messages
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: process
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: words
          group: group-1
        process-out-0:
          destination: counts
      kafka:
        bindings:
          process-out-0:
            producer:
              configuration:
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
          process-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: localhost:9092
            auto-create-topics: false
```

***Log***

```
2021-02-26 23:29:03.677  INFO 42872 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=kafka-messages-97a5b62c-b3a2-464f-84c2-5014818b7574-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kafka-messages] Subscribed to topic(s): words
2021-02-26 23:29:03.809  INFO 42872 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=kafka-messages-97a5b62c-b3a2-464f-84c2-5014818b7574-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kafka-messages] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2021-02-26 23:29:03.811  INFO 42872 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=kafka-messages-97a5b62c-b3a2-464f-84c2-5014818b7574-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kafka-messages] (Re-)joining group
2021-02-26 23:29:06.705  INFO 42872 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=kafka-messages-97a5b62c-b3a2-464f-84c2-5014818b7574-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kafka-messages] Setting offset for partition words-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=4, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
```

As you can see groupId is not set from yml file. I have spent a good number of hours on this but no luck. Please help.

***UPDATE***

GroupId seems to be applied correctly when I don't use streams API with my pom dependency modified to spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:3.1.1

Comment: It seems that `org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.6.0` is using application.id to set GroupId. Excerpts from StreamThread.java `String applicationId = config.getString("application.id");
        Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs = config.getMainConsumerConfigs(applicationId, ClientUtils.getConsumerClientId(threadId), threadIdx);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring; it is set by KafkaStreams itself.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#streamsconfigs

> **application.id**

> An identifier for the stream processing application. Must be unique within the Kafka cluster. It is used as 1) the default client-id prefix, 2) the group-id for membership management, 3) the changelog topic prefix.

Comment: Thanks Gary, yes I figured it out.